# How to repair corrupted .mat file after it was recovered by using recovery software

Tags: matlab, corruption, mat-file

I was at the middle of a project and accidentally deleted one of my major folder which contains all my signals.
All of the signals was in .mat format and each of them has considerably large size.
After taking my laptop to support center, they recovered my file but nearly all my .mat files could not be read (all other type such as .m or simulink file are readable).
I checked various method, but all of them says the .mat "file might be corrupt" so I want to see

1. Is there specific method to recover my missed .mat files?
2. Is there any way I could fix the corrupted .mat file or some part of it?

I checked various method such as

- loading .mat file in matlab
- checking the file by matfile
- try to read the ,.mat file by fopen and fread
- using "splitmat" code on my .mat file , as mentioned here [link] (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98890-how-do-i-recover-data-from-a-corrupt-mat-file)

but all of them says the .mat "file might be corrupt"

Comment: Does the .mat file have any size? If so, does it correspond to what you would expect?

Comment: I don't remember the original size but I suppose they are in the same range